# TwinCAT 3 integration with C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use C++ module with TwinCAT 3 to explore its potential.
However, I am stuck at the very beginning since I can´t create a new project.
I get this when I try to create a new C++ item [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGcEg.png) 
I've followed the instructions on system requirements [https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_c/126100789677070987.html&id=)](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_c/126100789677070987.html&id=) and so installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Universal Window Platform and Desktop Development with C++, I downloaded and configured 'Windows Driver Kit', and I have TwinCAT 3 XAE (running on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (shell)) installed.

I believe this has a simple explanation, but Iam not getting there. Has anybody had the same issue? Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the moment TwinCAT 3.1 cannot be integrated in Visual Studio 2019 and the Visual Studio 2013 Shell does not permit you to create TwinCAT 3 C++ modules. You need to have a Professional, Premium or Ultimate version for that.

So, I would advice you to install a Visual Studio 2017 Professional in order to develop TwinCAT 3 c++ modules.